# Cannot upgrade azure cli to the latest version

Tags: azure, azure-cli, kali-linux, azure-cli2

`az --version` showing an updated version available as shown below.

```
kali@kali:~$ az --version
azure-cli                         2.18.0 *

core                              2.18.0 *
telemetry                          1.0.6

Extensions:
interactive                        0.4.4
azure-devops                      0.19.0

Python location '/usr/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/kali/.azure/cliextensions'
Extensions system directory '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/azure-cli-extensions'

Python (Linux) 3.9.1+ (default, Jan 20 2021, 14:49:22) 
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


You have 2 updates available. Consider updating your CLI installation with 'az upgrade'

Please let us know how we are doing: https://aka.ms/azureclihats
and let us know if you're interested in trying out our newest features: https://aka.ms/CLIUXstudy
```

However, running `az upgrade` failed as shown below.

```
kali@kali:~$ az upgrade
This command is in preview and under development. Reference and support levels: https://aka.ms/CLI_refstatus
Your current Azure CLI version is 2.18.0. Latest version available is 2.19.0.
Please check the release notes first: https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli
Do you want to continue? (Y/n): Y
User install by explicit request
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-5vas80w4
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-9_ggxmc0
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-9_ggxmc0
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-9_ggxmc0
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-9_ggxmc0
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-cck39b_2
1 location(s) to search for versions of azure-cli:
* https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for https://pypi.org/simple
Loading KWallet
Loading SecretService
Loading Windows
Loading chainer
Loading macOS
Getting credentials from keyring for pypi.org
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/azure-cli/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21515
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/96/89adf026ed3a849b4fa00aeda1d4a32d0c7d6195167d5bff96d72fb8c278/azure-cli-0.1.0b4.tar.gz#sha256=66f7f40e1a14d0dbc93b2dd1ebdb018e87c4fe5eff19ddf4154a9794ed737ba1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b4
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8b/eb/38cdea1b151b09b779a8659272ca44ae0e942a9faa81ab6e7d5de648ffa4/azure-cli-0.1.0b7.tar.gz#sha256=e708ba091d3bac588db1ed140c71afe9b5acad921ca453b20535607063b09dab (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b7
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/93/d9/64ed394f8995addfa60256cd37f03a68b1ac34ab301f160c8d2444d2af13/azure-cli-0.1.0b8.tar.gz#sha256=99073bec56018094dbf961cf1edec6612a089a55de9c9267e320b618a6722742 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b8
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/aa/02d2080d5c36cbc9f35184f9601532f96dd793ef460e69d9a08869f1eb7c/azure-cli-0.1.0b9.tar.gz#sha256=d369336eacd610a700368d6767425d0c0d3f07f682e84f739add302df8786287 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b9
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/56/ee8f9a8841cd664d05c3227c2b4c5665488999dee26b384ef72a884f66e2/azure_cli-0.1.0b9-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=27e7ef2e568213f9c175253637103d8c30f3b2e6996913a7b2713f34a4c64753 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b9
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/aa/97986d5eb1f8f2cbabedac0909d899c7c14d5337fb1fcbc1134df1f0bb53/azure-cli-0.1.0b10.tar.gz#sha256=afa4b8a85cbdf2b35912b2e0e228b26e72295bb17dc6fe49bb557d98425cb780 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b10
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/c1/120735be1b101dfd214e997c735f50432bcd31f38cec80a9f2b3914005e8/azure_cli-0.1.0b10-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=50b9e82fd47b937f27526e73b956295e504510ef63671d09fe0eba6cae71fa16 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b10
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/62/1ec7e1685fa805322cad62a8a281008e21436bf97010f291b962840255fc/azure-cli-0.1.0b11.tar.gz#sha256=3b27e2e12730dd6e6a0c8178eaaffb43a704917093a75ad9f6289b9f42bdcd1f (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b11
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/c1/43d2193e0d9a8de4aa4cefce98789e890f8a0fac01a6e3d3809a5aac1af1/azure_cli-0.1.0b11-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=6d89a6f1b8581d13aba1e4c5597f2ccecfc877033e0ef7aee65893244e6b96e7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.0b11
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c0/d9/335f50396dbfcc60e97c17c043a5d96f210c083384c3800885a30d7e5d01/azure-cli-0.1.1b1.tar.gz#sha256=1fd0894e3e41d17051bdf9d2aa0fed727fee68e36748af2b423cde7fcd75807c (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.1b1
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/7a/f2c196802abcfa4bda3f57b8f5762941e2ad7f4ed36085f4634d5bf8a5f6/azure_cli-0.1.1b1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=4b6b3b1e3c2cbae42093f082c24197135333a3e0661c1337d7a7a387b36074d3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.1b1
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/f7/4a6acd919a39900393ad0358637feebbdfe832daf7a524ad90a1accd623e/azure-cli-0.1.1b2.tar.gz#sha256=bb026c7c277661a9244caee5b6e5a2034ccb88715a6fbed834b2c98061758225 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.1b2
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9e/55/15a6ccc5d39b5dcbffaf3d675c4d6bff1437d3558a84f7f6c48bd052aadc/azure_cli-0.1.1b2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8999f06968483761809756982e38e6b7a2c2eec06990a15988dcea81463f7e3d (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.1b2
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/80/eef12f5b91f172add55e77e4e2d2b67281f83573535fc39e464f88dc5648/azure-cli-0.1.1b3.tar.gz#sha256=9fee8704b51648b4c48139b5a6c54611bda0171b889845f92cbf567d729a3741 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.1b3
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/83/fe1fe785aea3c8f2ba0507e3597118b31d6fe7feb19b7abb85d64ee38810/azure_cli-0.1.1b3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=694a5d417b93249abe76442b388539f244ffe440242f44dd8b28ee60463478fa (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.1b3
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b3/85/e3cc3c9425b9036a2d99bd9a026ccd07c4a8ba365418384ec8cb46720204/azure-cli-0.1.2rc1.tar.gz#sha256=694d4faea5a3b70400d903485d0759483c51e9b34f3a0f61f74b8893a2ad7217 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.2rc1
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/b7/9ef06a4261923e57c4799ae2cdcbde5294b9ca3fc1e6558dd302414f1a24/azure_cli-0.1.2rc1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=08883cbe6afc071f7e1d176bd97ac5653985fea63e89cc25006aa05815e582b9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.2rc1
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/51/151bf2320a2b66df1da18adb29f3f3e50bb05153b7e07a129954c0148547/azure-cli-0.1.2rc2.tar.gz#sha256=82e4a9a0482eb4e26596263e792a2619eb1ce030d3a4f71bfadc647d329a1791 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.2rc2
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/c2/04c4a7fbab93d8c4b9a228b0dcd932011d90e6528bf65c58d4ccae8ab84c/azure_cli-0.1.2rc2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=125d1fe877b524387d994005d2d243d2055366e38bbc933e85ea6692b2ffc0a9 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 0.1.2rc2
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/99/5c6f6cffc15f94205426b346bb2b72add4ccab34246b4f291a26ea729b05/azure-cli-2.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=b676f3926bd95f638dc108defbef7d599a553a2c913e3687c57ec0ce810b5cda (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.0
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/f4/ad1fd2a52fe1867b861bf83eb8698c951bc779ebe06900044c2dd77b198a/azure_cli-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=2f8a416755fbe4a0b8f865f8ad904908b0570a9500d5bcb0e7a6d61ee5eec289 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.0
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/8d/07880a1312064b4e79984ee8b42ade7faaafc05a26d23e6108be00f12632/azure-cli-2.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=fd9346880cd7422daa9fe2cb62488b9f8c30eaddebcfda14ca535f92e244d6d3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.1
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8d/47/3520374e9aaa2c3392b5e6704a2f5a50a81eb57c35a3c0455e68d828c4a9/azure_cli-2.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=06a76bce90dfa6c7d46d95bf43de76c8516b99cdd68a867e677d89606fa4c40c (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.1
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/a8/f49399739a0cfc25f189431c84cb69e152699e95a044947cecc35a4a506b/azure-cli-2.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=f1f863d273124b9cdb4a7dfff8ab3f450dc2c773e8f31864a1073234ddf481d3 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.2
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/73/ac420dad3815fdca9d02d3b946c910146e6b82116ae04b350e118ae93f84/azure_cli-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=b1f37c80f251c48b24a394358f3622bb6f842da49e3c0db2c1a5009b436f5b2a (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.2
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/4f/8d5a2d2fd97eadb368203ed67783957bbf77c6ad4b439fbe9b523edad1e0/azure-cli-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=66ed9406469e2cb15435a32919f4cc27c1aa9d13099eab8f78648692c32c93e4 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.3
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/68/24c083720a6c1fb2586fc2ca1958394e63a924d777f7e73c011623644fef/azure_cli-2.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=932fea3678b1bd7e5c253c32dcad7f207da4e2e6e0e4b53c2248680695da1545 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.3
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/66/c0/01ccc683088945571ce4ba7a2e4dce6de182c84ed2438dcb11f589894e36/azure-cli-2.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=086c914b33fe60d7dc81e2f9a079bfd7fba23ec1cc4db74b1c4985b15299cd03 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.4
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bb/50/0c330278badcbb754d87e0eae94018e020dc63f60adedc5f001e68fbd6f8/azure_cli-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=3dcda1882f83dfb18e563ca0d4a4e67a214b895a29a917a96c443c1b4678a800 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.4
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/b9/9876a27f4c041a27b0982d604c82089f3ecca8d96c419940c6816562afd6/azure-cli-2.0.5.tar.gz#sha256=a6d6a340874b5d20f9b775c0488e29e6c1d84ed60ab6fdd093df8d8c17f42379 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.5
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/0d/061381aa8a06c1602e275d56d5461120abdd695c0a15cda0e68ed6ad04d4/azure_cli-2.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=0426afcd90eea185c59356703510173e0ca694c52aaf98186ace7e379d79ba10 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.5
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/02/14/99dca9249cf538faf8f0dd22f1ac8caeb7ccbfb42a5da49a6764335fe8c6/azure-cli-2.0.6.tar.gz#sha256=af2728b4592e5d54859136179ff056ba47e0dc2a24ab39f55800c3a97bb63d5e (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.6
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f3/f1/539b36e9c1d43fde00d716a4b6f3afc813312d4672ce18f9d75b87e5f7be/azure_cli-2.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=1ceaf955441a41e06052a850b85d1f314657b6a2ccc91ef5d928d6208ed4c52b (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.6
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/a1/7f65e21fbddf4e58071b44259a743d3c2d77151e06e5a3339c8981016e2e/azure-cli-2.0.7.tar.gz#sha256=d3abd2e460780a9999f056dcfee0a90377c2f6fcdb21ac2359922ae167b967b5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.7
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/ea/b232428a7aa3d05402c6b9cb2bd5092605ad1828d46f9a1d64b8b2a7f324/azure_cli-2.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=caac157a9c7ecc660c36e8fcb2ee2ddce952a65130b52723c76eb9a03e232076 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.7
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/30/fd64eb58816e9baf2afbe0dbc799d9d10898beb1fc168a41f4121f398fca/azure-cli-2.0.8.tar.gz#sha256=1a7f54723a6921febfe03b27a6461749a031977ea4eeb0363d179138822b81ac (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.8
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/9d/9d63bfc93de37edbb881234e8151fc8c1d0ab03d2e2f65b2146f46755995/azure_cli-2.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=6192dc8f89a72d881bb4b96ef103bf26e4e5fd4348165568b1d6d3636e0fdcef (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.8
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/4f/5f0c18ccf1547aeb3d4954067a4ffef765529a92ee57051a33cf6ca59a3a/azure-cli-2.0.9.tar.gz#sha256=395f8aa248029607b3661b04a99ac1f6fae916a28948a1d6b5a1cb3276101551 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.9
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/01/32aa35af620bb78e1fc7f23e7cf0b7dc091200bd6eaa48e05ad973d28102/azure_cli-2.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=a018419e59ffc1e7923f8f355467c056d92cde8ceb9bad262d9253c5808df9ce (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.9
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/03/90d55cff53ed30977009d3b9958a3e8f01a4990fe7e7e33d9a31550398fe/azure-cli-2.0.10.tar.gz#sha256=cd6b054e023ce2f1ebe313cff9a36ac833af6a383d12386b5c9e88027f52099f (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.10
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/2a/9a9d9013f458a8727c16e3da6053dac576eaad67a317de5b428cec9e3b93/azure_cli-2.0.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=f946acd31f3feb20f7851f0f3a69d26967b019ea7bcf57ba897d1ae773443c39 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.10
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5b/96/ca899c5b0625c03010c2f3157f35a352ebfaf2779869e202b9ddb45fc681/azure-cli-2.0.12.tar.gz#sha256=c2ddb89f4b0fba1b6a8d08c42fccd7cdbceea32d495f4c0fae45165f4f25071a (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.12
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4e/61/2f07b0f96df5ad7b6ea9474a643fc575559b2672b1a69bfba2a47fa88840/azure_cli-2.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=ed273192df698df9c374b4d540c7a195e15c40ddc6d0dd196f17210ed714e2de (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.12
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/cb/5b812f522443f40bd26bf2649feaf78f5f2c3b6c9467b38370ea4256e24a/azure-cli-2.0.13.tar.gz#sha256=c651d4a24f8002c601c532f566e22aa22614995bc7798b7bcea9c41e73383daf (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.13
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/37/987516e6c74f889dfc91bf488fd5bb4364e9dc19ef2b6af246ae4cf3f39f/azure_cli-2.0.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=703058f0b7fb0140041ce1339a5e7e52aa75f5295372384e31b8661e3cabb7eb (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.13
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/d0/1303facef574be538559922c1e87ce329440b018acc3a995d82502bb6533/azure-cli-2.0.14.tar.gz#sha256=f881bc9b6ebbbc01f3842c860d86e08d111de5fb5ef0617b7b2e6648d63c4d11 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.14
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/81/2aa2e0dee506b649bed7c7f74e2968e108dc67de7cff149a6872abdce0a2/azure_cli-2.0.14-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=33e383d96afa63d2342d0da143abfdb1bc04b0d14399829a9c3de9c45573f59b (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.14
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/f4/ddf55431de23c234db4eea7b1f64f37e76f16c0f5f669e218667d109ad41/azure-cli-2.0.15.tar.gz#sha256=84b13fbb61a06eeaeec96ab1bfb0dd54bfbb02e0368ea34390b5f53fc77e4625 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.15
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/54/8c5abd98354e775eb59250e014ab5628852b166ac8018c0d7065656ed1a3/azure_cli-2.0.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=61b2b5ed5ff64779f5f510be0ff88aa06f74cd6f7885c536f357ac2b99759437 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.15
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/27/842d204f1144ccb2c6d4572f3a98e680f406a0edb9f549473782b4b17cd5/azure-cli-2.0.16.tar.gz#sha256=168023bedf1a87d640737f1eac2276276dc1a3c89004f79e55c868bcc642c01d (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.16
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/9b/87f7aa336c0e8cf2337bb9854fb790f10909d73152f0d79abc35a82fc927/azure_cli-2.0.35-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=67b5c471a55154cbb1d7218763ad5f6a469ddfecabda64f7dba3f2f87b7e7f9c (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.35
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bf/97/e38df894a9710e4bbbdd6e67d9311703a88d1475d918998ef3ca31a4ca6a/azure-cli-2.0.37.tar.gz#sha256=ee39a831afbc2c9b13b51ed2274e87e07417b9f8b2ed7bea944a576c3864f340 (from https://pypi.org/simple/azure-cli/), version: 2.0.37
  Found link https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c8/e5/6f812d961fb6d481c6f75f1ed21446bed0288b66d9b7b2af8ee7c0ef2053/azure_cli-2.0.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=cd469c0cdeff83b69bd60c1d07f6360f7815efdf6d09cc367ae549ea72aa4b93 (from 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-mgmt-synapse~=0.6.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-mgmt-datalake-store~=0.5.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-cli-core==2.19.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli) (2.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sshtunnel~=0.1.4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli) (0.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-functions-devops-build~=0.0.22 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli) (0.0.22)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-mgmt-core<2.0.0,>=1.2.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-mgmt-appconfiguration~=1.0.1->azure-cli) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-mgmt-datalake-analytics~=0.2.1->azure-cli) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-storage-common~=1.4->azure-cli) (2.25.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-storage-common~=1.4->azure-cli) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-mgmt-nspkg>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-mgmt-dns~=2.1->azure-cli) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from websocket-client~=0.56.0->azure-cli) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-nspkg>=2.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-keyvault~=1.1.0->azure-cli) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-core<2.0.0,>=1.6.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-synapse-accesscontrol~=0.2.0->azure-cli) (1.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2.0.0,>=1.25.9->azure-cli) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna>=2.0.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2.0.0,>=1.25.9->azure-cli) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyOpenSSL>=0.14 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from urllib3[secure]<2.0.0,>=1.25.9->azure-cli) (20.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cffi!=1.11.3,>=1.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from cryptography<3.0.0,>=2.3.1->azure-cli) (1.14.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: paramiko in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from scp~=0.13.2->azure-cli) (2.7.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: psutil~=5.7 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: azure-cli-telemetry==1.0.6.* in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.0.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: jmespath in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: colorama~=0.4.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: PyJWT==1.7.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pkginfo>=1.5.0.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: msal-extensions~=0.1.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (0.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: argcomplete~=1.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: knack==0.8.0rc2 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (0.8.0rc2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: adal~=1.2.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.2.5)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: humanfriendly<10.0,>=4.7 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (9.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: msal~=1.0.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: vsts in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from azure-functions-devops-build~=0.0.22->azure-cli) (0.1.25)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: portalocker~=1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from msal-extensions~=0.1.3->azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (1.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyyaml in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from knack==0.8.0rc2->azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (5.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pygments in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from knack==0.8.0rc2->azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (2.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tabulate in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from knack==0.8.0rc2->azure-cli-core==2.19.0->azure-cli) (0.8.7)
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-9_ggxmc0'
CLI upgrade failed or aborted.
```

apt update shows following error.

```
kali@kali:~$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli kali-rolling InRelease
Err:2 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli kali-rolling Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.90.56.68 443]
Hit:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/azure-cli kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I update **az cli** to the latest avaialable version?

Comment: Microsoft Azure is a Platform as a Service and Infrastructure as a Service cloud computing platform. Use this tag for programming questions concerning Azure. General server help can be obtained at Super User or Server Fault

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Check out the similar issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11348).* Adding a summary here as per best practices:

Please install `libssl-dev, libffi-dev, python-dev, build-essential` before running the [script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/scripts/curl_install_pypi/install.py#L371). These are the requirements for debian using the script. It may also apply to deepin-generic.

Found a similiar issue: [MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli#1628](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-cli/issues/1628). If you know the debian system that is close to yours, you could replace `AZ_REPO=$(lsb_release -cs)` with something like `AZ_REPO=stretch` in step 3 of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: The links you provided seem to be for installing the Azure CLI. In my case, I was able to install it fine and use different commands, etc. The issue I have is when trying to upgrade and not sure how the links you provide are applicable to my scenario.

Comment: It is a similar error which you are getting, did you try these steps?